# How to pass search results from database into DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

As above. The user enters a keyword and click on search button to search for a row/rows in database, then the search should return the row/rows in a DataGridView form. I already have an exisiting `DataGridView dataGridView1` so how do I make use of `dataGridView1` to display the row/rows?

Comment: What are "the search results"? What form to they take? is it a `List<T>` of some type `T`? a `DataTable`? a single string? what?

Comment: Where do you want to take the results from? List? Dictionary? More info

Comment: editted. search for a row or multiple rows in database

Comment: How did you bind your data into DataGridView? Please share some codes.

Comment: @user1779026 that edit adds absolutely no information or context *whatsoever*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer here is "set it as your data-source", i.e.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = theSearchResults;
```

This will work if *either* the data (`theSearchResults`) is an `IList`, or an `IListSource` that *provides* an `IList`; ***and*** the metadata for the results can be obtained (which can be via the first row (if any), the *type* associated with an indexer `public SomeType this[int index] {get;}`, or an `ITypedList` implementation).

In human terms:

- it will work if the data is something simple like a *vector* (a 1-dimensional, 0-indexed array), a `List<T>`, etc
- it will work for most lists/collections that have at least one row and which are homogeneous (all the rows are of the same fundamental type)
- it will work for things like `DataSet` / `DataTable`
- and many other things, but not *everything*